# how should LaTeX know, where to break the 'equation' ... somewhere in the exponential function?

Tags: line-breaking

I have failed to command latex to automatically enter new line as shown in the picture below.[image]
Here is my command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
\title{Quantum Mechanics Homework 3 \& 4}
\author{Seng Sopheak}
\date{2014}
\maketitle
[...]
$= \frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^{1/2}}\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\Delta x^2\right)^{1/4}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{(x-\langle x \rangle)^2}{4\Delta x^2}-\frac{\frac{4i}{\hbar}(p-\langle p \rangle)(x-\langle x \rangle)\Delta x^2}{4\Delta x^2}-\frac{\frac{4i^2}{\hbar^2}(p-\langle p \rangle)^2\Delta x^4}{4\Delta x^2}-\frac{i}{\hbar}x(p-\langle p \rangle)+\frac{\frac{4i}{\hbar}(p-\langle p \rangle)(x-\langle x \rangle)\Delta x^2}{4\Delta x^2}+\frac{\frac{4i^2}{\hbar^2}(p-\langle p \rangle)^2\Delta x^4}{4\Delta x^2}}\mathrm{d}x$\\
[...]
\end{document}
```

I could use line breaker `\\`, but I wonder if there is a way for latex to automatically entering new line. Could you help me?
Sorry for my English.

Comment: Could you explain me in more detail. I am very fresh to LaTeX. I don't understand much about Environment.

Comment: Well you need to use suitable environments for working with maths.

Comment: My comment was no suggestion to edit the title!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Suggestion

Well, I see you're loading the `mathtools` package, bout you need to learn how to use it.

I don't use it, but I would use the [`amsmath` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) with good tools for this.

My suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
\title{Quantum Mechanics Homework 3 \& 4}
\author{Seng Sopheak}
\date{2014}
\maketitle

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        & =\dfrac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^{1/2}}\dfrac{1}{\left(2\pi\Delta x^2\right)^{1/4}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp \Biggl(-\dfrac{\bigl(x-\langle x \rangle \bigr)^2}{4\Delta x^2} \\
        & \quad -\dfrac{\dfrac{4i}{\hbar}\bigl(p-\langle p \rangle\bigr)\bigl(x-\langle x \rangle\bigr)\Delta x^2}{4\Delta x^2} -\dfrac{\dfrac{4i^2}{\hbar^2}\bigl(p-\langle p \rangle\bigr)^2\Delta x^4}{4\Delta x^2} \\
        & \quad -\dfrac{i}{\hbar}x\bigl(p-\langle p \rangle\bigr)+\dfrac{\dfrac{4i}{\hbar}\bigl(p-\langle p \rangle\bigr)\bigl(x-\langle x \rangle\bigr)\Delta x^2}{4\Delta x^2} \\
        & \quad +\dfrac{\dfrac{4i^2}{\hbar^2}\bigl(p-\langle p \rangle\bigr)^2\Delta x^4}{4\Delta x^2} \Biggr) \, dx
    \end{split} 
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

### Details

When you're typesetting maths in `LaTeX` you must to use a suitable environment for that. If your expression is in the middle of a paragraph, then you must to use `$ $` symbols for use the math mode. But if you need to display maths outside a paragraph, there are few ways to do it. My favorite is the environment `equation`.

As your expression is very large and you use a big operator (`\int`) to display the equation out the paragraph would be the best choice. However, even as display equation is too long to fit on a single line of text. Furthermore, most of it is superscripted by the exponential function.

As you might know, the exponential function can be denoted as `e^x`(Euler form) but sometimes also as `exp(x)`. When to use which? Part of it may be a matter of style or own taste. Personally, I prefer the Euler form `e^x` but when the exponent is large, visually is preferable the `exp` operator. In this case the exponent is huge... so you can imagine how you should express.

To do this, technically speaking, what I did was create a kind of array. To which I used in the equation environment, another called split. In such environment I use the ampersand of cells separator and double backslash as separator lines. (Imagine a table or matrix, in fact it is a convention in LaTeX using the `&` as separator and `\\` for a newline.)

I changed the macros `\frac` by `\dfrac` that comes with the `amsmath` package and allows better deployment of large fractions such as your case. I also used `amsmath` delimiters (`\bigl(, \bigr), \Biggl(` and `\Biggr)`)to improve the sizes of the parentheses.

Finally I used macros for math mode space to fit in some cases: `\quad` (an em space) and `\,` (thin space). You don't need to load any package for use them.

The starred version of `equation` environment is for avoid the equations numbering. (This is an amsmath feature also).

[image: Result of the answer]

Comment: `mathtools `*loads* `amsmath` —actually it's an extension to amsmath.

Comment: @Bernard Great!, is nice to know it, then should I add the commented lines at my answer?

Comment: I would check if there's no problem (one never knows…), then I would uncomment the lines. My opinion is that, except perhaps for very simple documents, one should systematically load mathtools rather than amsmath, it's a long-established package that really brings many functionalities.

Comment: @Bernard: I hope, Barbara Beeton does not read your comment ;-)

Comment: @Bernard well I have to check the documentation and improve my practices.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer O.O Why not?

Comment: @Aradnix: Barbara is the maintainer of `amsmath` See her profile: http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Now I see, that explains a lot of things...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I really don't see why. For me, mathtools doesn't compete amsmath, it supplements it.

Comment: @Bernard: It was  joke ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- i'm not personally responsible for maintaining `amsmath`, but i'm a member of, and often the "mouthpiece" for, the *group* that is responsible for `amsmath`.  and we have nothing against `mathtools` -- the ideas in it are both good and well implemented.  there is a note on our "to do" list (which, sadly, won't be addressed soon) to consider merging these ideas into `amsmath`, of course with the consent and cooperation of the author of `mathtools`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no automatic way to break such formulae. How should LaTeX understand the syntax of your equation? Math needs some manual treatment, I fear.

Please note that you should put such big equations in an `equation` environment. You can split your equation by the sub-environment `split` or you insert it directly in an `align` or similar.

Here is, how you could do it in your case. If you get the feeling that the equation gets to difficult (kind of the case in your post...), you should consider rewriting it to something else.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    &= \frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^{1/2}}\frac{1}{(2\pi\Delta x^2)^{1/4}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{e}^Z\,\mathrm{d}x
    \intertext{where}
    Z &= -\frac{(x-\langle x \rangle)^2}{4\Delta x^2}-\frac{\frac{4i}{\hbar}(p-\langle p \rangle)(x-\langle x \rangle)\Delta x^2}{4\Delta x^2}-\frac{(\frac{4i}{\hbar})^2(p-\langle p \rangle)^2\Delta x^4}{4\Delta x^2} \notag\\
    &\qquad-\frac{i}{\hbar}x(p-\langle p \rangle)+\frac{\frac{4i}{\hbar}(p-\langle p \rangle)(x-\langle x \rangle)\Delta x^2}{4\Delta x^2}+\frac{(\frac{4i}{\hbar})^2(p-\langle p \rangle)^2\Delta x^4}{4\Delta x^2} \notag\\
    &= -\frac{(x-\langle x \rangle)^2}{4\Delta x^2}-\frac{i}{\hbar}(p-\langle p \rangle)(x-\langle x \rangle)-\Bigl(\frac{2i}{\hbar}\Bigr)^2(p-\langle p \rangle)^2\Delta x^2 \notag\\
    &\qquad-\frac{i}{\hbar}x(p-\langle p \rangle)+\frac{i}{\hbar}(p-\langle p \rangle)(x-\langle x \rangle)+\Bigl(\frac{2i}{\hbar}\Bigr)^2(p-\langle p \rangle)^2\Delta x^2 \notag
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know what all this stuff corresponds to, but may I point that one can simplify further: there remains only the first term of both lines of the last equality (and already in the next to last one). But maybe the O.P. has good reasons not to simplify…

Comment: @Bernard yes, you can go much further, but I spent enough time on this. Don't know, what the OP wants, but she/he gets an idea. (btw: I didn't see the equal terms when editing around. What a shame. TeX-source is no good for doing math...)

Comment: Quite true for complex equations. That's why my editor is configured to have some kind of ‘pretty-editing’ (Greek letters, products, sums) using a font that has enough maths symbols.

Answer (score 1):

I provided three variants of a solution.

1. Use `multline` to split the exponent at appropriate places.
2. Also use `multline`, but simplify the exponent.
3. Simplify the exponent and add some substitutions (I chose the magnitudes `\Delta x` is raised to)

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*\ii{\mathrm{i}}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
  = \frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^{1/2}} \frac{1}{(2\pi\Delta x^2)^{1/4}}
  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \diff x \exp
  \Biggl(
  -\frac{(x-\braket{x})^2}{4\Delta x^2} \\
  -\frac{\frac{4\ii}{\hbar}(p-\braket{p})(x-\braket{x})\Delta x^2}{4\Delta x^2}
  -\frac{\frac{4\ii^2}{\hbar^2}(p-\braket{p})^2\Delta x^4}{4\Delta x^2}
  -\frac{\ii}{\hbar}x(p-\braket{p}) \\
  +\frac{\frac{4\ii}{\hbar}(p-\braket{p})(x-\braket{x})\Delta x^2}{4\Delta x^2}
  +\frac{\frac{4\ii^2}{\hbar^2}(p-\braket{p})^2\Delta x^4}{4\Delta x^2}
  \Biggr)
\end{multline*}

\begin{multline*}
  = \frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^{1/2}} \frac{1}{(2\pi\Delta x^2)^{1/4}}
  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \diff x \exp
  \Biggl[
  \frac{1}{4\Delta x^2}
  \Biggl(
  -(x-\braket{x})^2 \\
  -\frac{4\ii}{\hbar}(p-\braket{p})(x-\braket{x})\Delta x^2
  -\frac{4\ii^2}{\hbar^2}(p-\braket{p})^2\Delta x^4
  +\frac{4\ii}{\hbar}(p-\braket{p})(x-\braket{x})\Delta x^2 \\
  +\frac{4\ii^2}{\hbar^2}(p-\braket{p})^2\Delta x^4
  \Biggr)
  -\frac{\ii}{\hbar}x(p-\braket{p})
  \Biggr]
\end{multline*}

\begin{equation*}
  = \frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^{1/2}} \frac{1}{(2\pi\Delta x^2)^{1/4}}
  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \diff x \exp
  \Biggl[
  \frac{1}{4\Delta x^2}
  \bigl(\mathcal{F}_0 + \mathcal{F}_2 + \mathcal{F}_4\bigr)
  -\frac{\ii}{\hbar}x(p-\braket{p})
  \Biggr]
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{align*}
  \mathcal{F}_0 &= -(x-\braket{x})^2 \\
  \mathcal{F}_2 &= -\frac{4\ii}{\hbar}(p-\braket{p})(x-\braket{x})\Delta x^2
  +\frac{4\ii}{\hbar}(p-\braket{p})(x-\braket{x})\Delta x^2 \\
  \mathcal{F}_4 &= -\frac{4\ii^2}{\hbar^2}(p-\braket{p})^2\Delta x^4
  +\frac{4\ii^2}{\hbar^2}(p-\braket{p})^2\Delta x^4 \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also split the equation with multiplication symbol as shown below
code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
\title{Quantum Mechanics Homework 3 \& 4}
\author{Seng Sopheak}
\date{2014}
\maketitle
\begin{align*}
&=  \frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^{1/2}}\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\Delta x^2\right)^{1/4}} \\
&  *{} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{(x-\langle x \rangle)^2}{4\Delta x^2}-\frac{\frac{4i}{\hbar}(p-\langle p \rangle)(x-\langle x \rangle)\Delta x^2}{4\Delta x^2}-\frac{\frac{4i^2}{\hbar^2}(p-\langle p \rangle)^2\Delta x^4}{4\Delta x^2}-\frac{i}{\hbar}x(p-\langle p \rangle)}\\
& *{}  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{+\frac{\frac{4i}{\hbar}(p-\langle p \rangle)(x-\langle x \rangle)\Delta x^2}{4\Delta x^2}+\frac{\frac{4i^2}{\hbar^2}(p-\langle p \rangle)^2\Delta x^4}{4\Delta x^2}}\mathrm{d}x 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! Sorry, but this is mathematically not the same as the original formula.

Comment: 1st: An integral over a product of functions is in general not the product of the integrals on the single functions ... 2nd: The  diffenterial `dx` is missing on the first integral...

Comment: Yes. You are correct. The second integral should not be there. However I wanted to divide the lengthy integral into first integral e^() * e^()dx. I could not bring big bracket covering (e^() * e^())dx after first integral.